# Installation Error scikits talkbox python

Tags: python-3.x, installation, scikits

Tried to install scikits talkbox python 3.6 on my windows 10.
Visual Studio :14 
I am getting the below error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1171: unable to load mspdb140.dll (error code: 127)
error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\lib.exe build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\scikits\talkbox\linpred\src\levinson.obj /OUT:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\clpc.lib" failed with exit status 1171
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

First install NumPy+MKL then SciKit-Learn from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). Steps are

1. Download .whl file to some folder
2. `pip install file.whl`